# How do I get this banner to show up using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get an image to take up the width of the page but for some reason it wont show up. I think I've set up the path to the banner correctly i did
background-image:url('/images/banner.png');

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<nav>

</nav>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Shiny Leaf Studio</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Username</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wide">
        <div class="col-xs-5 line">
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 logo">Logo</div>
        <div class="col-xs-5 line">
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body,html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.wide {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 1px);
  background-image:url('/images/banner.png');
  background-size:cover;
}

.wide img {
  width:100%;
}

.logo {
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:800;
  font-size:14pt;
  padding:25px;
  text-align:center;
}

.line {
  padding-top:20px;
  white-space:no-wrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this clas sin `.wide`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<nav>

</nav>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Shiny Leaf Studio</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Username</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wide container-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-5 line">
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 logo">Logo</div>
        <div class="col-xs-5 line">
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please make a fiddle for your code or share your site if its live

Comment: use row class instead of `.container-fluid`

Comment: use `<div class="wide row">` instead of `<div class="wide container-fluid">`

Comment: what?? you want that two div's on full page and its now on full page do u want something else??

Comment: No I only wanted a picture to span the width of the page below the nav thats it

Comment: I just don't get why it dosen't work bc it should be simple I think Im just gunna scrap the whole thing